# Data Grid Row Header Not Resizing To Contents

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, datagridrowheader

I'm customizing a DataGrid so that the user can enter information directly into the header via a TextBox.

The problem that I am having is that the row headers are not resizing to match the size of the contents when the text changes:

Before: 
[image]

After: 
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the header does not reduce in size to match the text boxes once the size of the text box has been reduced to match the new text.

In compliance with the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Requirements:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MCVE"
    xmlns:lib="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="MCVE.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="Source" Type="{x:Type lib:String}">
            <lib:String>Foo</lib:String>
            <lib:String>Bar</lib:String>
            <lib:String>Baz</lib:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource Source}"
        RowHeight="50">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBox FontSize="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="This Is A Test" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Type some stuff into any of the row headers. Then clear it to reproduce.

So what can I do to enforce the row header width and make certain that it maintains the smallest width possible ( without encroaching on the actual row header contents )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `SizeChanged` event for the `TextBox` elements and keep track of their width's. Try this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<TextBox, double> _widths = new Dictionary<TextBox, double>();
private void TextBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    _widths[textBox] = textBox.ActualWidth;

    double largestWidth = _widths.Values.Max();
    DataGridRowHeader header = FindParent<DataGridRowHeader>(textBox);
    dg.RowHeaderWidth = double.NaN;
    if (header != null)
        dg.RowHeaderWidth = dg.RowHeaderActualWidth > largestWidth ? largestWidth : double.NaN;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBox FontSize="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="This Is A Test"
                                           SizeChanged="TextBox_SizeChanged" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: This breaks the MVVM approach I am trying to maintain, but it did lend itself well to accomplishing my goal Thanks.

Comment: Why would this break the MVVM pattern? This is pure view logic only.

Comment: Your solution implements code directly into the view class code outside of XAML ( the code-behind ) and requires that the "View" connect to that code. My understanding of MVVM is somewhat limited, and could be mistaken, but I believe that having code in a views "Code Behind" goes against the MVVM patter.

Comment: Your assumption about MVVM is wrong. MVVM is not about eliminating *view* related code from the views where it belongs. It's about separation of concerns. Handling some logic related to how the width of the RowHeaderWidth is set in the view model would be wrong. This is purely view related and should be handled in the view, or in the control.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for clarifying my views on the subject.